# " flip-up/down the switch " or "turn up/down the switch"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

" flip-up/down the switch " or "turn up/down the switch", I'm wondering which one sounds more natural or both of them are good. Help me pls.

Comment: It's usually turn on/off a switch.

Comment: Or turn the light/power/etc. on/off.

Comment: @KillingTime thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: @RosieF thank you for your helpful answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of switch you mean to some extent. The ones found in room settings (both lights and power socket switches) are often referred to differently from those in vehicles and on control panels.

I assume that you are referring to the now rather rare switches which have a protruding stick which must be lifted or pressed down to operate it rather than the, nowadays, more common 'rocker switch' which can be operated by pressing in the end which is currently raised.

The best term for a switch which has a rod or stick operation in vehicles and control panels is a "toggle switch" and this might be applicable to room switches now. When rocker switches were introduced for this purpose the older type used to be called an "ordinary" or "conventional" switch but the rocker type is so ubiquitous now that you can't really use that term.

Interestingly the term "toggle" which originally referred to the mechanical lever part of the switch is now used in computer coding to refer to any two-state operation which might, in a physical system, be controlled by a toggle switch so you will hear people saying things like "The caption on the button toggles between 'go' and 'stop' depending on the state of the program".